# jquery anchor click event inside another function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am writing a code to handle anchor click event in jquery. There is an input text to enter size value and there is an anchor link beneath this control to show the size table.

Below is the html part:

```
<div class="sizeDetail">
    <input type="text" id="sizeValue" name="sizeValue" class="formControl" />
    <div class="showTableLink">
        <a href="#">Show size table</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a function 'sizeChartEvents' linked to 'sizeValue' control through code which handles all the events related to this.

```
function sizeChartEvents(sourceControl){
    // code to validate source control

    // show size chart
    function showSizeChart(){
         $('#sizechart').show();
    }

    // handle on click of anchor
    $(".showTableLink a").on("click", function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        showSizeChart();
    }
}
```

The above anchor click event does not fire when run.

But if I add the click event on document ready function it is working fine.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.showTableLink a').click(function(){
            $('#sizechart').show();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the first click event not working. what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Please try to read more about differences between event listener and event handler.

Comment: hi, can i see al your code on codesandbox?